# calling a function procedure under the click event of a button

Tags: vb.net

i created a function procedure and i need to the action to be carried out when i click a button, but a don't know how to call the function procedure under the click event of the button control. please could someone come to my rescue?

Comment: What you are trying to do is well documented... have you search on google / stackoverflow before asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling a Sub, just use the [Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz(v=vs.80).aspx#Y925) statement, e.g.

```
Call mySub(arg1, arg2)
```

If it's a Function that returns a variable, Dim a variable in your click event and set it equal to that function.

```
Dim myVar as String
myVar = myFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: The Call keyword is old VB6 syntax, just omit it.

Comment: ... even in VB6, it was optional

Comment: In VB6 if you omitted it you couldn't use parentheses then, right?